# Regex for strings that contain at least one number and one letter and allows non-alphanumeric

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that checks for at least one number and one letter, I've searched on SO and haven't found one that matches the requirement exactly, for example, the one below checks for at least one number and one letter, however, it won't work when the string contains anything that's not letter or number:

`\d+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+\d`

For example:

all of the below should match the regex:

`hello123`
`hello 123`
`hello!@#$123`

but above regex only matches the first string, because the other two have non-alphanumeric in them.

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one- `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`

It checks for at least one number and one letter-

```js
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('hello123')); // true
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('hello 123')); // true
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('hello!@#$123')); // true
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('!@#$123')); // false
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('!@#')); // false
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('123')); // false
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/.test('hello')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*)|(?:.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*)
(?:                   )                          - Match non-capturing group:
   .*                                              - Match anything 0-n times
     [a-zA-Z]                                      - Match a single letter
             .*                                    - Match anything 0-n times
               [0-9]                               - Match a number
                    .*                             - Match anything 0-n times
                       |                         - OR
                        (?:.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*)  - Match the same thing as before, 
                                                   but with first the number, then the letter
```

[Try it here.](https://regex101.com/r/IrzegC/1)

This one tries to find a single letter, ignoring anything before and after, and a single number afterwards OR first a single number, then a single letter.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this regex `[^0-9a-zA-Z]*\d++[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]++[^a-zA-Z]*|[^0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]++[^0-9]*\d++[^0-9]*`

The first expression checks for the case where the number comes first (preceded by other non-alphanumeric) followed by any characters which is not a letter (the letter is not considered since it would be matched by the next portion of regex) then it checks whether one or more letters come followed by anything else if present.

The second expression after the or(`|`) similarly accounts for the case where the number comes first